# Store data permanently to Persistent storage

Tags: codenameone

Can data be permanently stored in Persistent storage, such that anytime the applications loads I can get the last inserted item?

If yes, can I get a code sample or a link to some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Of course! That's how modern databases work.

My advice is to consider storing your data as JSON in MongoDB for maximum portability:

> MongoDB is an open-source document database that provides high
>   performance, high availability, and automatic scaling.

I highly recommend [mlab](https://mlab.com/), who offer MongoDB as a service - you can host up to 500MB on one or more databases.  Follow the steps in their [getting started](http://docs.mlab.com/) documentation (5-10 mins).  Then download [Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/) and configure it with the connection settings from mlab; you'll be able to view all of your databases, collections (aka tables) and documents (aka datums), and interact with them using either basic point and click, or programmatically using its [Mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/client/) interface.

Comment: Will this example work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275975/how-to-use-codename-one-storage

Comment: Yes, but it assumes you have the Codename One platform already setup, and says nothing of DB setup, etc.  If I had to persist data to a DB from scratch, I would mlab + Robomongo, per my answer.

Comment: Notice that the question is tagged [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/). Codename One is a cross platform mobile application framework so this will not work on the device, you would need to connect to a server to use permanent storage with Mongo. Probably not what Giftor is asking.

Comment: Yes! Not what am talking about. I want to work with sqlite database, but I discovered it's not supported on some platforms. That's why I went for the storage which is supported on all platform. The example you gave at the above link  worked

Answer (score 0):

See the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html) section on storage where the various types of storage options are discussed in depth. There are many samples in that section but you will need to clarify a more exact use case of what you are trying to accomplish.

If you just want to save one variable you can use something like:

```
Preferences.set("var", val);
String var = Preferences.get("var", defaultValue);
```

Comment: Thanks. I get it now